# logged user not persist between different projects

Tags: laravel, session, authentication, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I have more than 2 projects, both running on xampp localhost and using built in auth laravel. both ver 5.3 and ver 5.2
If I log into both projects, one of the projects will be logged out immediatley.
Both projects are in htdocs folder.
Both using same file session configuration, which come from laravel original configuration.
How to solve this? Will it be a problem if hosted in shared hosting? What causes the problem?

Comment: same or different domains?

Comment: both on localhost using xampp on htdocs folder, project1 folder,project2 folder and so on. localhost/project1/public and localhost/project2/public

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The session cookie is defined on a per-domain basis, unless defined otherwise.  So if you have two projects using the same session variables on the same domain, it will cause conflicts.

If you use a different domain, then no problems, so I don't foresee this problem carrying over to a shared host unless you stick with the same domain and the projects in directories.  Most sites use sub-domains to separate application sessions.

Comment: Just to add that this issue could be easily fixed changing the cookie name for each project running on the same domain. This could be done changing the value of the config array key 'cookie' in config/session.php